# python ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000005 (mpi)

Tags: python, crash, mpi4py

I'm having some problems using the mpi4py library.
Actually, in the first part of the code the process seems to work. I debugged the code and the information is sended between ranks, and they finally recieve the matrices prod_aux_rec,prod_aux_rec_.
But then, I try to apply similar process and I get the following error: python ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000005 (mpi).

```
    list_int_aux[0] = idx
    list_int_aux[1] = start_feature_y
    list_int_aux[2] = end_feature_y
    list_int_aux[3] = t
    for r in range(size):
        comm.Isend(list_int_aux, dest=r, tag=0)

    'suppose the server is agent rank=0'
    'ask from coeficients c,c_ to agents'
    for r in range(size):
        #MPI.Status()
        comm.Recv(list_int, source=r, tag=0)
        #source = status.Get_source()
        prod_aux = np.zeros((args.batch_size,list_int[2]-list_int[1]))
        prod_aux = xl[list_int[0]:(list_int[0] + args.batch_size), :].dot(wl[:, list_int[1]:list_int[2]])
        comm.Isend(prod_aux, dest=r, tag=1)
        np.random.seed(list_int[3]+rank+r)
        wl_noise[:,list_int[1]:list_int[2],:]=args.std*np.random.randn(wl_noise.shape[0], list_int[2] - list_int[1],args.batch_size)
        prod_aux_ = np.zeros((args.batch_size, list_int[2] - list_int[1]))
        for i in range(args.batch_size):
            prod_aux_[i, :] = xl[list_int[0] + i, :].dot(wl[:, list_int[1]:list_int[2]]+args.mu*wl_noise[:,list_int[1]:list_int[2],i])
        comm.Isend(prod_aux_, dest=r, tag=2)

    for r in range(size):
        comm.Recv(prod_aux_rec, source=r, tag=1)
        prod[:, r, :]=prod_aux_rec
        comm.Recv(prod_aux_rec_, source=r, tag=2)
        prod_[:, r, :]=prod_aux_rec_
```

Second process is similar as first code, but the information to exchange is higher than in the first part (in first part nrows=batch_size=300, and the second is 8k).
When i tried to run it I got the following error: python ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000005 (mpi).

I thought that the problem is that maybe matrix was too big. So I decided to send less information several times, as you can see in the second part of the code.

But again, the same error appears when it tries to recieve comm.Recv(prod_aux_rec_main_aux, source=r, tag=8+c).

```
args.batch_size=300
batch_idx = np.arange(args.batch_size)
c=0
for r in range(size):
    #MPI.Status()
    comm.Recv(list_int, source=r, tag=7)
    # source = status.Get_source()
    source = r
    prod_aux_main = np.zeros((xl.shape[0],list_int[2]-list_int[1]))
    prod_aux_main = xl.dot(wl[:, list_int[1]:list_int[2]])

    for s in range(25):
        comm.Isend(prod_aux_main[batch_idx,:], dest=r, tag=8+c)
        if s<24:
            batch_idx = np.remainder(batch_idx + args.batch_size, args.n_train)
        c=c+1
    comm.Isend(prod_aux_main[(batch_idx[-1]+1):,:], dest=r, tag=8+c)

    c = c + 1
    np.random.seed(list_int[0]+rank+r)
    wl_noise_main[:,list_int[1]:list_int[2],:]=args.std*np.random.randn(wl_noise.shape[0], list_int[2] - list_int[1],xl.shape[0])
    prod_aux_main_ = np.zeros((xl.shape[0], list_int[2] - list_int[1]))
    for i in range(xl.shape[0]):
        prod_aux_main_[i, :] = xl[i, :].dot(wl[:, list_int[1]:list_int[2]]+args.mu*wl_noise_main[:,list_int[1]:list_int[2],i])
    for s in range(25):

        comm.Isend(prod_aux_main_[batch_idx,:], dest=r, tag=8+c)
        if s < 24:
            batch_idx = np.remainder(batch_idx + args.batch_size, args.n_train)
        c = c + 1
    comm.Isend(prod_aux_main_[(batch_idx[-1]+1):,:], dest=r, tag=8+c)

'recieve c,c_ from agents'

prod_aux_rec_main = np.zeros((args.batch_size, end_feature_y-start_feature_y))
prod_aux_rec_main_ = np.zeros((args.batch_size, end_feature_y-start_feature_y))
prod_aux_rec_main_aux = np.zeros((xl.shape[0]-7*args.batch_size,  end_feature_y-start_feature_y))
prod_aux_rec_main_aux_ = np.zeros((xl.shape[0]-7*args.batch_size,  end_feature_y-start_feature_y))
c=0
batch_idx = np.arange(args.batch_size)
for r in range(size):
    for s in range(25):
        comm.Recv(prod_aux_rec_main, source=r, tag=8+c)
        if s < 24:
            batch_idx = np.remainder(batch_idx + args.batch_size, args.n_train)
        prod_main[batch_idx, r, :] = prod_aux_rec_main
        c = c + 1
    comm.Recv(prod_aux_rec_main_aux, source=r, tag=8+c)
    prod_main[(batch_idx[-1]+1):,r,:] = prod_aux_rec_main
    c=c+1
    for s in range(25):
        comm.Recv(prod_aux_rec_main_, source=r, tag=8+c)
        if s < 24:
            batch_idx = np.remainder(batch_idx + args.batch_size, args.n_train)
        prod_main_[batch_idx, r, :] = prod_aux_rec_main
        c = c + 1
    comm.Recv(prod_aux_rec_main_aux_, source=r, tag=8+c)
    prod_main_[(batch_idx[-1]+1):,r,:] = prod_aux_rec_main_
```

Moreover, if i try to execute manually (being in rank=0) the recieve function comm.Recv(prod_aux_rec_main, source=1, tag=8+c) from rank 1, i get the following message:

```
Message from rank 1 and tag 23 truncated; 471680 bytes received but buffer size is 160000
```

Than you very much, let's see if somebody has ever had the same problem.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem i think. It was problem with the c variable, it should be inside the for function. And the prod_aux_rec_main array should be declared before the whole code.